# lazy_high_chart: how to send evenet with '<' operator and not with '&lt;'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I'm work with ROR and ruby 1.9.2.

I'm use lazy_high_chat gem and want to set an evevnt.

The way is to set JS function as string;

It's O.k.

But when I used '<' operator in the code, there is an error in the JS.

This is simple example for my code:

```
%= high_stock("my_id", @h) do |c| %>
       <%= CGI.unescapeHTML('options.chart.events.selection = function(x) {var y =8;if(y<10){alert(1);}else{alert(2);}}')%>
<%end %>
```

I tried to use CGI.unescapeHTML but in the js still Appears '<'

What can I do?

Thanks in advence,

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this:

```
<%= high_stock("my_id", @h) do |c| %>
       <%= 'options.chart.events.selection = function(x) {var y =8;if(y'%>
       <
       <%=10){alert(1);}else{alert(2);}}')%>
<%end %>
```

and it work.